# if $\bar{X}\overset{p}{\rightarrow} \mu$ then $f(\bar{X})\overset{p}{\rightarrow} f(\mu)$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, weak-convergence, probability-limit-theorems

Is it true that if $\bar{X}\overset{p}{\rightarrow} \mu$ then $f(\bar{X})\overset{p}{\rightarrow} f(\mu)$ taking $f$ a continuous function and "$\overset{p}{\rightarrow}$" meaning "Convergence in Probability"? And if true, what would be a simple proof.

And the general case is forward too? This is:

if $X\overset{p}{\rightarrow} Y$ then $f(X)\overset{p}{\rightarrow} f(Y)$ taking $f$ a continuous function?

Comment: $f$ continuous yes; $f$ merely measurable, no.

Comment: $\newcommand{\pto}{\overset{p}\to}$If $X_n\pto X$ and $f$ is continuous, then $f(X_n)\pto f(X)$. See e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_mapping_theorem#Convergence_in_probability